# If $\lVert A \rVert$ is a matrix norm, then $\lVert A+A*\rVert$ is also a matrix norm?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I was reading about matrix norms and I found this statement. Any ideas how this one can be proved? A* is the complex conjugate transpose of A. In a simpler question, is even $\lVert A*\rVert$ a matrix norm?

Comment: What if $A^* = -A$ ?

Comment: That one case shows that $||A+A^*||$ is not a norm. What was the definition of "norm" again???

Comment: The matrix norm is a function ||.||: Κ^mxn -> R that satisfy 5 properties
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Answer (score 0):

Since $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ have the same non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$, as a result, $\|A^*\|^2=\lambda_{max}(AA^*)=\lambda_{max}(A^*A)=\|A\|^2$ and thus $\|A\|=\|A^*\|$. From sub-additive property of norm $\|A+A^*\|\leq{\|A\|}+\|A^*\|$ implies $\|A+A^*\|\leq{2\|A\|}$.